# How do I perform a heart transplant?

Tags: surgeon-simulator-2013

Assuming that I have the capability to [properly hold the instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTHtk.jpg), what are the steps and instruments to use, to successfully (and optimally) perform a heart transplant without letting the patient's blood level get to 0ml?

I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly here:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This video will help you a lot.

The procedure is 'simple': Brake the ribcage with hammer,take out the lungs, cut out old heart using scalpel, throw it outside the body cavity, take the new heart and just place it inside the 'hole' approximately where old one was. Done.

How you remove all those stuff depends on your choice,skill and luck but using mentioned tools is fastest and with minimal risk of major blood lost.

If you do get major blood loss you can always stop it by injecting the patient with green needle few times,careful not to inject yourself.

Comment: The scalpel is a better way to get the heart out because the saw does a lot of collateral damage and causes blood loss over time, which severely limits the time you get to work. Also note the new hart seems to have to be in there JUST right, I couldn't get it to recognize that it was in, myself.

Comment: Just like in real life!